# Cypher query getting stuck

Tags: neo4j, cypher

With below cypher query am trying to first get User node using *IdObject* which has a uniqueness constraint and updating a property named *NameFull*

```py
match(u:User{IdObject:{user_id_object}}) set u.NameFull={user_name}
```

But query never completes have to terminate it manually each time.

Also  attaching a screenshot of query plan

[image: simple query execution plan]

Any ideas why it's taking infinite time and any solutions to it?

Comment: Some futher info would help: What version of Neo4j? What's the output of `CALL dbms.listTransactions()` and `CALL dbms.listQueries()`? Is the unique index finished creating? `CALL db.indexes()` will give a completion percentage or error state - is there anything flagging up there?

Comment: Thanks @Pablissimo looks like unique index in progress was the reason of it, Tried it today morning and it works perfectly fine.